# Postfix header logging

Tags: postfix, logging, email-server, linux

I want to know what lines need to be added to header_checks in order to make postfix log replyto entry. I already tried this with no chance :

> /^Reply-To:.*$/     INFO replyto:$1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1 refers to a matched substring, but your pattern does not define any substrings. Try:

```
/^Reply-To:(.*)$/ INFO replyto:$1
```

Check http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html